# Ember.js - Application <div/> is rendered twice?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using the following Ember.js stack:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.1.2 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.2 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I declared an `application.hbs` Handlebars template which renders my `App.ApplicationView`

```
{{#view App.ApplicationView}}
  {{outlet 'modal'}} {{outlet 'notificationCollection'}}
  {{#if isUserAuthenticated}}
    {{render sidemenu authenticationState=isAuthenticated}}

    {{outlet 'upperNotification'}}

    <div id="main" class="main">
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  {{else}}
    {{outlet}}
  {{/if}}
{{/view}}
```

and for debugging purposes I added the `gotcha` to the `classNames` array of `App.ApplicationView`. When I now inspect the DOM, I can see that `App.ApplicationView` is rendered twice (and also boxed):

```
...
<div id="appRoot" class="ember-application">
  <div id="ember444" class="ember-view gotcha">
    <div id="ember445" class="ember-view gotcha">
      ...more content..
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

**EDIT:**
I should have tried it first, before posting it here at stackoverflow... if I remove the `{{#view App.ApplicationView}}{{/view}}` declaration, it get's only rendered once, as expected ;)

So, the question which remains a miracle to me is **is `Ember.js` really generating an enclosing `<div id="ember666" class="ember-view"></div>` for every `{{outlet}}`**??

---

<strike>Why would `Ember.js` handle it this way? How can I prevent it from rendering `App.ApplicationView` twice?</strike> And, besides that, is `Ember.js` really generating an enclosing `<div id="ember666" class="ember-view"></div>` for every `{{outlet}}`? (I'm seeing this behaviour within my application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, yes `{{outlet}}` will enclose your template in a `<div>`. However, you can change that behavior by specifying a view class on the outlet and defining the view class' `tagName` property to whatever you want.

For example, the outlet

```
{{outlet viewClass=App.HeaderContainer}}
```

With view

```
App.HeaderContainer = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  tagName: 'header'
});
```

will wrap the outlet in a `<header>` tag.

Comment: thanks a lot! didn't read that anywhere at Ember documentation(?)

Comment: It's in the API docs http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet